# Pseudo code to recursively construct java object using Reflection

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection

I am trying to write code for function that will help me to deep print a java code that will help me with the construction  of a given new java pojo's objects.

 function will get the class type and it will print the initialization code,

Example: For class Foo with 2 int members and one String member:

```
 Class Foo
     int a,b;
     String c;
```

the call to the helper function will be :

```
 void printCode(Foo.getClass())
```

The function will trace all setters of the object and it will print the calls as text, output of the function for Foo class will be:

```
 Foo foo = new Foo();
 foo.setA();
 foo.setB();
 foo.setC();
```

Another more complex example for this classes (A,M,N):

```
Class A
    setFoo(int){};
    setBar(int){};
    setM(M class){};
    setN(N class){};
    setNAndM(M,N){};

Class M
    setBaz(String){}

Class N
    setQux(Float){}
```

Function signature will be:

```
void printCode(Class clazz)
```

For the start class A The desired program output will be (output is java code as string):

```
M m1 = new M();
m1.setBaz(/*some random String here*/);

N n1 = new N();
m1.setQux(/*some random Floathere*/);

M m2 = new M();
m2.setBaz(/*some random String here*/);

N n2 = new N();
m2.setQux(/*some random Floathere*/);

A  a = new A();
a.setFoo(/*some random data here*/);
a.setBar(/*some random data here*/);
a.setM(m1 - /*object name from previous iteration*/);
a.setN(n1 - /*object name from previous iteration*/);
a.setNAndM(m2,n2 - /*object name from previous iteration*/);
```

I am able to do 99% percent of the work, the stop condition should be - to get to primitive or string type - otherwise use recursion for the object..

The only thing I am missing is the actual recursion logic to traverse the setters correctly, would like help with Pseudo code, something like:

```
void **printCode**(Class clazz){
    list setters = getAllSetters(clazz);
    for each setter{
         list parameters = getAllParameters(setter);
              if not all parameters are primitive or string:
              for each setter{
                         if(parameter is not (String or primitive))
                                   **printCode**(parameter)
                             }
                }
             print construction code for the object here;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: When **printCode** is executing, the parameters to the setters are not available. Perhaps you should look at the getters?

Comment: I just need setters parameter types - its available..

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: I don't understand yur actual problem. Do you want your pseudo code checked or do you want your Pseudocode translated into Java or do you want only the logic for getAllParameters(setter)?

Comment: I am looking for an Idea, Pseudocode not code, on how to recursively traverse object and print information according to its setters.

Answer (score -1):

I made a Java Class out of your pseudo code. I hope it is what you are looking for:

```
public class ReflectionPrinter {

public static void printCode(Class<?> clazz) {

    Constructor<?>[] cons = clazz.getConstructors();
    List<Method> setters = getAllSetters(clazz);

    for (Method setter : setters) {

        Class<?>[] params = setter.getParameterTypes();

        for (Class<?> param : params) {

            if (!isPrimitiveOrString(param)) {
                printCode(param);
            }
        }
    }

    // print out
    for (Constructor<?> con : cons) {
        System.out.println("new " + con.getName() + "()");
    }

    for (Method setter : setters) {
        System.out.println(clazz.getSimpleName() + "." + setter.getName() + "()");
    }

    // skip
    System.out.println();

}

public static List<Method> getAllSetters(Class<?> clazz) {
    List<Method> setters = new ArrayList<Method>();

    for (Method m : clazz.getMethods()) {
        if (m.getName().startsWith("set")) {
            setters.add(m);
        }
    }

    return setters;
}

public static boolean isPrimitiveOrString(Class<?> paramClass) {

    return paramClass.isPrimitive() || String.class.equals(paramClass);
}
```

If you also need the parameter names of the setter parameters, you could use Paranamer http://paranamer.codehaus.org/.

Another possibility would be using AspectJ http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/ to trace all constructor and/or setter calls. But then it will only print the setter methods, which are actually called. In AspectJ there are pointcuts available especially for setter methods and setting variables. I think we can find the right pointcut, if you need help with that.

Comment: Thank you but no need for actual code,just Pseudocode on how to follow objects.

Comment: Are you kidding me? What makes the difference for you? 
Should I remove the modifiers or what? >:(
I don't know what you will do with that, but you can use it as a template the same way you use pseudo code.

Comment: run your code on the second example, it won't print correctly.

Comment: Then specify what won't be printed correct and what should be printed

Comment: @user648026 Nobody can help you, if you don't describe what you want.